# When initializing a numpy array, is it better to specify the shape with a list or a tuple?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

My professor always uses a list; I'm curious whether this is faster.

I mean is this:

```
np.zeros((10, 10))
```

or this:

```
np.zeros([10, 10])
```

preferred? Is one faster than the other?

Comment: It doesn't matter, and there is no reason to care.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is definitely inconsiderable, but tuples are basically tend to be more optimized. Because tuples are immutable objects and to gain that they've had to give up some features that makes them optimized in some situations. In this case you can simply benchmark both snippets:

```
In [81]: %timeit np.zeros((10, 10))
447 ns ± 20.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [82]: %timeit np.zeros([10, 10])
491 ns ± 3.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

It shows that using lists is ~50 nanoseconds slower which can't make any difference in your day-to-day programming tasks. Unless you are a quantum physicist ;).